# parallel processing: class file has wrong version 49.0, should be 48.0

Tags: java, linux, terminal, parallel-processing, supercomputers

I run my code in supercomputer by used terminal.

I have 2 kind of code: 1- sequential  and parallel (shared memory)

the sequential one it run correctly, but when I run the SM I have this error
 when I enter th command javac :

> mycode.java:7: cannot access edu.rit.pj.Comm 
>   file has wrong version 49.0, should be 48.0 Please remove or make sure
>   it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath. import
>   edu.rit.pj.Comm;

the library for parallel is: parallel java.

Answer (score 1):

You trying to access a Java 5 library with a Java 4 compiler. This cannot work.

I wonder if you really need to use these old Java versions.

Comment: I try to download jdk7 I used jdk8 but this version of the JDK is no longer current ?

Comment: jdk9 is brand new, but jdk7 and jdk8 are still widely used.